# Aylien Sentiment Analysis using Console application

Tags: c#

I'm facing a problem. I am using Aylien API for sentiment analysis. When i run this code, i will get a value of neutral 0.99823.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client("ID", "Key");

        string filename = "tweet.txt"; // Declare the file name 
        string inputString = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename); // Read all text in File to String.

        Sentiment sentiment = client.Sentiment(text: inputString);

        Console.WriteLine("The Tweets are : " + sentiment.Polarity + " " + sentiment.PolarityConfidence);
        Console.WriteLine(sentiment.Subjectivity + " " + sentiment.SubjectivityConfidence+"\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close...");
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

However when i run my second code to invoke the method from another console application, it always display positive 1. Do anyone know why?

```
var proc = Process.Start(@"C:\\ConsoleApplication1");
        proc.WaitForExit();
        var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
```

Comment: Maybe you're reading two different tweet.txt files.

Comment: i'm reading from same txt.file. No matter what text i put in them, the result will always be positive 1.

Comment: The exit code is not the value you output to the screen,  you need to read the standard output to get your value.

Comment: In this case, how do i get the desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the exit code from the process, which generally indicates success/failure, 0 generally means the process ended successfully, anything else  generally means something went wrong, although the creator of your app could be returning anything they want.

If you want to get the output from the actual application you should read the standard output from process by doing the following:

```
        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\\ConsoleApplication1";
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += Proc_OutputDataReceived;

        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        proc.WaitForExit();

        private static void Proc_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }
```

Comment: Actual result is suppose to be :( neutral 0.99997 subjective 1). After implementing your code, i got, (positive 1 subjective 1) constantly